# How to return feature dependency percentage from sklearn prediction?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I am relatively new to Python and Machine Learning.

I have a basic dataset for insurance fraud and a script that generates the model and runs the predictions.

I am able to output the accuracy percentages, but I would like to also output the feature dependencies: For example, what role did each attribute play in the prediction? The policy_number would be 0.0% where as the claim_amount would likely be 56.2%, does this make sense?

Is there a scikit function for this? Also, is "feature dependency" even the correct term?

Here is a sample of the prediction piece of the code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
sgdc = SGDClassifier()
sgdc.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = sgdc.predict(x_test)

prediction = pd.DataFrame(y_pred)
```

Is there a way to extract the feature "importance"?
Thank you very much, again, for taking the time.

EDIT: Ok, I think I made some progress, but I am not sure what to make of the results as the values do not seem to be percentages. I have added the following code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
model = ExtraTreesClassifier()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
coef = pd.DataFrame({''Columns'': x_train.columns, ''Importances'': np.transpose(model.feature_importances_)}).sort_values(by=[''Importances''], ascending=False)
print(coef.nlargest(10, ''Importances''))
```

Here is the resulting output:

```
                                Columns  Importances
125      incident_severity_Minor Damage     0.042847
40                insured_hobbies_chess     0.041505
126        incident_severity_Total Loss     0.028544
124              collision_type_Unknown     0.019634
41            insured_hobbies_cross-fit     0.014173
1                       policy_state_OH     0.009765
16                     insured_sex_MALE     0.009697
57       insured_relationship_own-child     0.009582
25   insured_occupation_exec-managerial     0.009513
5                 policy_deductable_500     0.009146
```

Is there a step I need to take to convert these values to get percentages?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide your code, a piece of data and the expected output?

Comment: This will depend on your model choice. Many ML models are black-boxes and will not allow you to see feature importance or contribution. In others, e.g. a Logistic Regression, you can get coefficients for all your predictors that are interpretable. As [rvbarreto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1966942/rvbarreto) said, please post more details.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. I have added the prediction piece of the code.

Comment: @Matt it's unlikely that it can be read as percentages, it might be Value of Information, or entropy, but it probably depends upon the model used. Just use it as a ranked list and graph a histogram accordingly, the difference between the features is typically more telling than the values themselves.